# Do Edge not store cookies data in Mac?

Tags: cookies, browser, microsoft-edge

I recently shifted from Windows to Mac and has been using Edge for last 5-6 months. But on checking website cookies data, it is showing that 0 bytes is stored for all websites. So, do Edge in Mac not store cookies data or there is some other method?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLgRi.png)

I was expecting that the size of cookies for websites more than 0 byte as I have been using Edge for all my work.

Comment: Hi, i guess, the byte-count is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage . Other than that 1 cookie stored, it says...

Comment: May I know if you have tried my suggestion?

Comment: @KendrickLi yes, it was most probably an issue from edge side, it is now showing the cookies data stored for all websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a UI issue, only the size being not correctly shown. You can still see detailed information of these cookies. Having checked Microsoft Edge on Windows, I've found the same issue.

I suggest sending feedback to the Edge Dev Team. You can simply do it by pressing `Alt` + `Shift` + `I` in Microsoft Edge.